# Datagridview currentrow or selectedrow

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hi i have a two DataridViews and i want `datagridview1's` first row to be the currentrow or selected row so when i click "add to cart" button i don't have to click the first row and it will go to `datagridview2.`

[image]

But i can't seem to do it. It still enter validation that say please choose product first. `dgv1.Rows[0].Selected = true;` is not working.

I can do it manually by clicking a row first then clicking "add to cart" button and it will go to `datagridview2`. But i want to do it automatically.
To give you an idea what i am trying to do is barcode scanning that when you scanned a barcode it will show in the datagridview1 and automatically go to `datagridview2`.

To cut the story short all i need is programmatically select datagridview1's first row to be the "current row" or "selected row" for my code to work.
You can put it as, I want to programmatically "click" first row.

But this is my code if you guys want to see.
this is my code for the barcode textbox textchanged event:

```
 private void txtBarcodeSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtBarcodeSearch.Text != "" && txtBarcodeSearch.Text.Length == 13)
        {          
            crud.FillDataGrid("Select ProductID,BrandName,GenericName,Form,Dosage,Quantity,SellingPrice,D,VE from Products where (Status = 'Active' and Quantity > 0) and Barcode Like  '%" + txtBarcodeSearch.Text + "%'  ", ref dgvPOSproduct);

            dgvPOSproduct.Rows[0].Selected = true;
            clicktry();

            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ProductID";
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Brand";
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Generic";
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Form";
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Dosage";
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Qty";
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Price";
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[7].HeaderText = "D";
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[8].HeaderText = "VE";

            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[0].Width = 65;
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[1].Width = 80;
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[2].Width = 80;
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[3].Width = 58;
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[4].Width = 58;
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[5].Width = 45;
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[6].Width = 55;
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[7].Width = 35;
            dgvPOSproduct.Columns[8].Width = 35;

            if (dgvPOSproduct.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                dgvPOSproduct.Rows[0].Selected = true;
                clicktry();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            dgvProductSettings();
        }


    }
```

this is the clicktry method code:-

```
 private void clicktry()
    {
        if (!validateProduct())
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (!QtyDialog())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!notIncartyet())
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int str, qty;
            str = Convert.ToInt32(storeqty.Text);
            qty = Convert.ToInt32(quantity.Text);
            temporaryquantity.Text = str.ToString();

            if (str < qty || str == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Insufficient Stock", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                continuetocart();
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the continue to cart method:-

```
  private void continuetocart()
    {
        dgvPOSproduct.CurrentCell = dgvPOSproduct.Rows[0].Cells[0];     
        qty = Convert.ToInt32(quantity.Text);
        unitprice = Convert.ToDouble(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
        totalprice = qty * unitprice;
        unittotal.Text = totalprice.ToString("0.00");

        addData
            (
            dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), //prod id
            dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), //brand
            dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), //dosage
            dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString(), //qty
            quantity.Text,
            unittotal.Text,
           dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString(),
            dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString()
            );

        int dgvPOSquantity = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString());
        int dgvnewquantity;
        dgvnewquantity = dgvPOSquantity - qty;
        dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value = dgvnewquantity;
        discountremoveitem();

    }
```

Comment: validateProduct() is showing this validation message? You check there dgvPOSproduct.CurrentRow for null?
How crud.FillDataGrid() loads data to grid?

Comment: Thank you sir i realize my validation is wrong. When i click a cell in datagridview its ID is placed in a textbox and my validateProduct() is just checking if that label is null or not. Whats the properway to validate if a product is not yet selected or currently selected sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

//declare a global variable

```
int ? selectedRow = null;

public void LoadList()
{ 

// reset global variable 
selectedRow = null;

List<string> collection = new List<string> { "Item 1" };

gridView.DataSource = collection ;

if (gridView.Rows.Count = 1)
{
  selectedRow = 0;
}

}
```

on your add to cart event do something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (selectedRow.HasValue)
   {
     DataGridViewRow dgRow = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow.Value];

    //move your data to cart

    // reset variable
    selectedRow = null;
   }
   else
   {
   //show a message that none is seleted;
   return;
   }

}
```

Comment: It says datagridview does not contain definition for DataBind and SelectedRow sir. and no selectedindex too

Comment: and there is no gridviewrow but there is datagridviewrow

Comment: Ok i thought it was a web application. I've updated my response. my bad :)

Comment: Yes sir i will. i still can not seem to make it work. its giving me the "show a message that none is seleted".(i put it in a messagebox). Give me a few moments sir. i think its because my code is messy.

Comment: Remember your data returned must be one before the variable will have a value

Comment: yes sir after i fire the barcode scanner it results to one row of item. and i put the event on that textbox textchanged. do you want me to update the questions so you could see the changes i made?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151400/discussion-between-ziregbe-otee-and-futuredev).

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between the concept of currentrow and a row that is selected, because current row is a singular property and can only ever refer to one row, but selectedrow can be a collection. Currentrow refers to the row whose cell has the dotted box/keyboard focus around it

I think you should adjust the logic of your program so that instead of trying to ensure that current row always has a value, it should look to see if current row is null. If it is null and there is only one row contained in the grid, take that row. If there are more than one row, ask the user to click on a row they want

Comment: Thank you sir i tried doing that but its still not working. maybe there is something else wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot set the CurrentRow property directly, (it is readonly) the CurrentRow is always the row of the current cell, which you can set.  So after your data has been loaded, you can ensure that the first row is current by default by adding the following line:

```
dgvPOSproduct.CurrentCell = dgvPOSproduct.Rows[0].Cells[0];
```

You should check before attempting this that the Rows count is greater than 0, otherwise you will get an index out of bounds error.

Comment: Thank you sir but it did not work unfortunately. problem is almost solve now thank you